# Python Dict elements access

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to extract only values from dict and place it in String array.

I have tried using `dict.values()`, but I'm getting below error:

```
Dictionary:[{'_id': 'CA'}, {'_id': 'TX'}, {'_id': 'FL'}]
```

**Code:**

```
for key,value in States_dict.items():
    States.append(value)
```

**Error:**

```
[{'_id': 'TX'}, {'_id': 'FL'}, {'_id': 'CA'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthiktvs/DB_project/hello.py", line 64, in <module>
    for key,value in States_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

`

Comment: That's not a dictionary. That's a list.

Comment: From what I infer, States_dict is a LIST, not a dict!; try: `for dct in States_dict: States.append(dct['_id'])`, or even more simply: `States = [ dct['_id'] for dct in States_dict]`

Comment: @Swifty thank you  for loop did work and got what I needed